# What does this code do in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

```
def host = /\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-])*?)(:|\/)/
assertHost 'http://a.b.c.d:8080/bla', host, 'a.b.c.d'
def assertHost (candidate, regex, expected){
    candidate.eachMatch(regex){assert it[1] == expected}
}
```

I know the above code is **asserting** my inputs! But in line 4, inside the closure, the magic variable (it) is being represented in an array! I'm bit confused on it. How does it work?

How does this work in Groovy (illustrate with simple code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html:

```
replaceAll

public String replaceAll(String regex, Closure closure)

Replaces all occurrences of a captured group by the result of a closure on that text.
For examples,

assert "hellO wOrld" == "hello world".replaceAll("(o)") { it[0].toUpperCase() }

assert "FOOBAR-FOOBAR-" == "foobar-FooBar-".replaceAll("(([fF][oO]{2})[bB]ar)", { Object[] it -> it[0].toUpperCase() })


Here,
     it[0] is the global string of the matched group
     it[1] is the first string in the matched group
     it[2] is the second string in the matched group
```